# Mad hatter full calendar color events Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i got some problem with change event color when I set title like '`Wydzial 1`' etc.
I know I must fetch title from db next use if to check title but next I don't know what to do.
I must do something like that: I create event with title '`Wydzial 1`' and get event with color:red, Next i want make event with title '`Wydzial 2`' with blue color. Something like that.
 Now its working all adding event with time and other but I dont know how make different color for event.

Controller:

```
/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $event = HomeModel::all();


    if($event->count()>0)
    {
        foreach ($event as $eve) 
        {
              $all_day = $eve->day;
              $events[] = \Calendar::event(
              $eve->title,
              $eve->all_day,
              $eve->start,
              $eve->end,
              $eve->id

              );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $events = [];

    }

    $titles = HomeModel::where('title')->get();

    if($titles == "Wydzial 1") {
        $color = '#378006'; 
    } elseif ($titles == "Wydzial 2") {
        $color = '#ff0000';
    } elseif ($titles == "Wydzial 3") {
        $color = '#73e600';
    } else  {
        $color = '#0066ff';
    }

    $calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events)
        ->setOptions([
            'FirstDay' => 1,
            'contentheight' => 650,
            'editable' => false,
            'allDay' => false,
            'aspectRatio' => 2,
            'slotLabelFormat' => 'HH:mm:ss',
            'timeFormat' => 'HH:mm',
            'color' => $color,           
            ])->setCallbacks([]);

    return view('home', compact('calendar'));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can pass the color as an option too ([docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/))? pseudo code:

```
$dbEvents = HomeModel::all();

foreach($dbEvents as $dbEvent) {
    if($dbEvent->title == "Wydzial 1") {
        $color = '#378006'; 
    } elseif ($dbEvent->title == "Wydzial 2") {
        $color = '#ff0000';
    } elseif ($dbEvent->title == "Wydzial 3") {
        $color = '#73e600';
    } else  {
        $color = '#0066ff';
    }

    $events[] = \Calendar::event()->setOptions([
        'title' => $dbEvent->title,
        'color' => $color,
    ]);
}

$calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events)->setOptions([
        'FirstDay' => 1,
        'contentheight' => 650,
        'editable' => false,
        'allDay' => false,
        'aspectRatio' => 2,
        'slotLabelFormat' => 'HH:mm:ss',
        'timeFormat' => 'HH:mm'
])->setCallbacks([]);
```

Comment: if i made like u write its doesnt showing events.;/